# Locating custom files in iOS app

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, nsbundle, nsfilehandle, mainbundle

I need to place some files in my iOS app initially and with app run copy them to Documents.

I placed them to main bundle, but I can not move them. Then I am trying to do it I have an error.

I find out that those files are not writable.

So how can I accomplish that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an initial version of the files in the Documents folder by copying them from your bundle. The bundle itself is read-only.